# C++ parameter pack as variadic template

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, std

I tried to build a function with a variable number of arguments which are of different types (string, double, int, bool). For this purpose I uses a variadic template. The function arguments are passed to a std::tuple, whose values will be extracted later. But my application runs into compile errors.

**Error:**
Error C2440 "Initialisation": "char *" cannot be converted in "int" (translated to EN).
This for the "int" argument, that obviously will be recognized as "char *" by the compiler. Commenting/Deleting the errorneous lines, the type recongnized during runtime ist correctly "int".

**IDE:**
Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, V 15.5.6

**Example:**
An easy code example, that has all essential features of the proper project is attached below. NB: The compilation of this code example works fine, no errors and variable types/Values and output as expected:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>

using namespace std;

template<typename ... T>
int func1(string s, T... args) {
    //creating the tuple ...
    auto argsT = make_tuple(args...);

    //run through the variables
    double p0{ get<0>(argsT) };
    string p1{ get<1>(argsT) };
    int p2{ get<2>(argsT) };
    bool p3{ get<3>(argsT) };
    char p4{ get<4>(argsT) };
    int p6{ get<6>(argsT) };

    string w{ s };
    std::cout << w.c_str() << std::endl;

    double z = p0 * p6;

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    func1("Kuckuck",1.0, "Hello", 4, false, '\n', "bye", -5, true, '\t');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a6963e66fb0ea68) (gcc/clang).

Comment: If you go to `get<I>` with fixed types, you don't need variadic template Btw.

Comment: *"The compilation of this code example works fine"* So why are you showing it, then? If you need help resolving a compiler error, show an example that actually exhibits that error. In other words, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: please provide an example with the unexpected error

Comment: Let's guess `int p5{ get<5>(argsT) };` -- "bye" -> int?

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you tried to do something like:

```
int p5{ get<5>(argsT) };
// "const char *" cannot be converted to "int"
```

This should work:

```
const char* p5{ get<5>(argsT) };
```